# Link to "Job alerts" is broken on Newsletters settings page

Tags: bug, profile-page, hyperlinks

If I go "Edit Profile & Settings" tab and then to "Newsletters" sidebar link I find myself on the page where link to "Job alerts" in sidebar is broken.

In other words if I'm at page `https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/newsletters/1113207` link "Job alerts" points to `https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/job-alerts?` (which is 404), while should point to `https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/job-alerts/1113207`.